# ibgf detector<bgr> does not contain a definition of forgroundmask

Tags: c#, kinect

Building a face detection program using Kinect.
Errors in following code points:
**Foreground Mask, OnDetection**

```
     _forgroundDetector.Update(image);
    //update the motion history
    _motionHistory.Update(_forgroundDetector.ForgroundMask);


    MCvConnectedComp comp = motionComponents[c];
    //reject the components that have small area;
    if (comp.area < minArea) continue;
    OnDetection();
    isMotionDetected = true;
```

Comment: Please edit this question and provide the full error and error location.

Comment: @CydrickT is right, you did not want to take pane to even describe your problem in detail, but, still took the pain to post this? Please provide more details, so that the members who have information about this can help you out.